# How can I defined inbound rules to my elastic beanstalk worker to only accept ips become of my SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, worker

On my Worker (AWS elastic beanstalk worker), I received lot of request like that :

```
151.100.143.22 (-) - - [14/Sep/2017:10:11:55 +0000] "HEAD http://34.224.82.145:80/mysql/pMA/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
151.100.143.22 (-) - - [14/Sep/2017:10:11:56 +0000] "HEAD http://34.224.82.145:80/sql/phpmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
151.100.143.22 (-) - - [14/Sep/2017:10:11:56 +0000] "HEAD http://34.224.82.145:80/sql/php-myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
151.100.143.22 (-) - - [14/Sep/2017:10:11:56 +0000] "HEAD http://34.224.82.145:80/sql/phpmy-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
151.100.143.22 (-) - - [14/Sep/2017:10:11:57 +0000] "HEAD http://34.224.82.145:80/sql/sql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
151.100.143.22 (-) - - [14/Sep/2017:10:11:57 +0000] "HEAD http://34.224.82.145:80/sql/myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
151.100.143.22 (-) - - [14/Sep/2017:10:11:57 +0000] "HEAD http://34.224.82.145:80/sql/webadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
151.100.143.22 (-) - - [14/Sep/2017:10:11:58 +0000] "HEAD http://34.224.82.145:80/sql/sqlweb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
151.100.143.22 (-) - - [14/Sep/2017:10:11:58 +0000] "HEAD http://34.224.82.145:80/sql/websql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
151.100.143.22 (-) - - [14/Sep/2017:10:11:58 +0000] "HEAD http://34.224.82.145:80/sql/webdb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
151.100.143.22 (-) - - [14/Sep/2017:10:11:59 +0000] "HEAD http://34.224.82.145:80/sql/sqladmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
151.100.143.22 (-) - - [14/Sep/2017:10:11:59 +0000] "HEAD http://34.224.82.145:80/sql/sql-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
```

And my server stop to work (I need to restart it) so, I added inbound rules : `HTTP TCP 80 127.0.0.0/8` it works except now, my worker don't succeed to listen/write data come to my default SQS queues.

This is my last access_log to show you, the cronjob works but not the main queue (queue/received) :

```
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Sep/2017:16:31:00 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/products/getProductForId HTTP/1.1" 200 41 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Sep/2017:16:31:00 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/999 HTTP/1.1" 200 30 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Sep/2017:16:31:27 +0000] "POST /queue/received HTTP/1.1" 500 495 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Sep/2017:16:31:59 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/999 HTTP/1.1" 200 30 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Sep/2017:16:32:00 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/products/getProductForId HTTP/1.1" 200 41 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
```

Do you know, how can I defined inbound rules to my elastic beanstalk worker to only accept ips become of my SQS queue

Thanks

Comment: Do your SQS have a security group? Do you have a fixed range of IPs for your SQS requests?

Comment: Thanks @eqperes to help me, I don't have a security group for my SQS, we can do that? And Not I don't have fixed range of IPs of my SQS Requests, I thought I was impossible to do that too

Comment: SQS doesn't originate the connections.  The worker connects *outbound* to SQS and then SQS pushes the messages over the connection that the worker establishes.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot, so why when I restrict the inbound rules (not the unbound) the worker can't save data/execute task given in my default SQS queue? (But cron jobs work perfectly)

Comment: I admit, that part is confusing.  The http logs under normal conditions might shed some light on the issue.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the http log (var/log/access_log) show only the cronjob and http request (like above) but not the message received since SQS queue.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : I added my last access_log to show you, the cronjob works but not the main queue (queue/received) : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/97cbce94206a9c0a8820c142bc0b86fe#file-access_log-L3

Comment: I admit, I don't understand what's happening here.  127.0.0.1 is not blocked by security group rules, under any circumstances, so even with no access allowed, that should still work.  When you say "rules" you are referring to security groups, **not** Network ACLs... correct?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes I'm referring to security group: inbound allow `HTTP 80 127.0.0.0/8` and outbound `HTTP 80 0.0.0.0/0` and when I set inbound rules `127.0.0.0/8` to `0.0.0.0/0`, the worker with main queue (POST queue/received) works perfectly but my worker can be "attacked"